# java derby database query, with user input text

Tags: java, derby

I have a java derby database, I can write to and read from the database.

I am having trouble:

Making it so that the text that the user enters into the text field, is then incorporated into the database query to determine the results displayed.

I tried it this way, the results were, if I click the search button, it will return the info/query into the "run" screen, **not** actually incorporating the user input into the query tho, I have to do that in the code, by replacing the abc to the number in the database.

Do I have to create some kind of command line argument? set the variable differently? Can I just replace the query info where the database info goes with a variable like how I tried in the upcoming example?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

    String abc = jTextField1.getText();
    String data = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
    try (
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
          data, "app", "app");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement())   { 
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            ResultSet rec = st.executeQuery(
              "select ROW1, ROW2, ROW3, ROW4, ROW5 from APP.NAME1 "
                      + "where (ROW4 = 'abc')");
        while (rec.next())  {
            System.out.println("ROW1:\t"
          + rec.getString(1));
            System.out.println("ROW2:\t"  + rec.getString(2));
            System.out.println("ROW3:\t"  + rec.getString(3));
            System.out.println("ROW4:\t" + rec.getString(4));
            System.out.println("ROW5:\t"  + rec.getString(5));
            System.out.println();
        }
        st.close();

    } catch (SQLException s)  {
        System.out.println("SQL Error: " + s.toString()  + " "
              + s.getErrorCode() + " " + s.getSQLState());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString()
      + e.getMessage());
    }                                        
}
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the variable correctly. Instead of setting the ROW4 to `'abc'` you need to set the variable. Try this.

```
"select ROW1, ROW2, ROW3, ROW4, ROW5 from APP.NAME1 " + "where (ROW4 = '"+abc+"')"
```

Its always better to use preparedStatement. this will avoid lot of problem related to SQL Injection.

```
String selectSQL = "select ROW1, ROW2, ROW3, ROW4, ROW5 from APP.NAME1 where ROW4 = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, abc);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
```